# Special way for differentiating polynomial?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, programming

Is there any simple way of computing the derivative to a complex polynomial of form

$$\left( z-z_{0} \right)\left( z-z_{1} \right)\left( z-z_{2} \right)...\left( z-z_{n} \right)=0$$

so that you do not have to multiply out the whole equation? I am trying to write a program which needs the exact derivative of the polynomial. My current approach is to write lots of complex buggy code to multiply out all powers of $z$, where I can  then differentiate.

Comment: Well, if that's $f(z)$ then $f'(z)=\sum_{k=0}^n \prod_{j \neq k} (z-z_j)$. Does that help?

Comment: Exactly, just use the product rule.

Comment: @Ian Yes that's perfect thank you :)

Comment: you still need to write a lot of basically the same code to get the final result

Comment: Except at the roots you have $f'(z)=f(x)\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac1{z-z_i}$.  When $z=z_i$ you have $f'(z_i)=\prod\limits_{j \neq i} (z-z_j)$